# Replace last occurrence of word in string jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex, replace

Hello I'm trying to replace the last occurrence of `foo` in the string `code`.
It's worth mentioning that `foo` is a variable containing a random string - this needs to be parsed into the regex.

```
$(target).html(code.replace(foo, replaced_text));
```

Maybe using `new RegExp()` in some shape or form would be a good port of call - although injecting `foo` gets unexpected results.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What RegExp have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply ensure that no other `foo`s follow using [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$(target).html(code.replace(/foo(?!.*foo)/, replaced_text));
```

Or given that `foo` is a variable:

```
$(target).html(code.replace(new RegExp(foo + "(?!.*" + foo + ")"), replaced_text));
```

Comment: thank-you, although foo is a variable containing any random string, how would I parse that into the regex pattern?

Comment: @Tommay, you can use `new RegExp(foo + "(?!.*" + foo + ")")` as first argument of the `replace`.

Comment: Thank-you, I shall accept answer in 4 minutes, why not update your original for others.

Answer (score 2):

Use the greediness of `*`

```
$(target).html(code.replace(/(.*)foo/, "$1" + replaced_text));
```

or

If `foo` is a variable.

```
$(target).html(code.replace(new RegExp("(.*)" + foo), "$1" + replaced_text));
```

If the variable `foo` variable  contain special characters.

```
> var foo = "$foo$"
> new RegExp("(.*)" + foo.replace(/(\W)/g, "\\$1"))
/(.*)\$foo\$/
```

Comment: thank-you, although foo is a variable containing any random string, how would I parse that into the regex pattern?